# UIWebView Delegate Deallocates in the Middle of didFinish Handler

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

My UIViewController is getting deallocated in the middle of a delegate callback.  Here's what happens:

1. `UIWebView` begins loading
2. User presses cancel
3. `UIWebView` begins sliding out
4. The request finishes, calls the `didFinish` handler
5. **IN THE MIDDLE** of the `didFinish` handler (like right between two lines of code) the viewcontroller runs dealloc
6. Everything is deallocated, delegates cleared, web requests stopped
7. The handler resumes in a deallocated state, causing a BAD_ACCESS exception

I've checked - everything is running on the main thread.

**How do I make sure dealloc isn't called in the middle of my handler?**

*Side question - how is this not a problem with all delegates? This terrifies me.*

Comment: Some code would help, and how is everything set up?

Comment: have you tried calling `[webView stopLoading]` when the user presses cancel?

Comment: I assume your webview is sliding out of view with a `dismissModalViewController`? If so why not clear the delegate and stop the loading of the webview before that happens?

Comment: Thanks @Rog. Clearing everything from `dismiss` does fix the problem. But I'm not sure it guarantees anything - it gives the web controller some extra time to finish its handler, but what if it wasn't enough time? What if I was dismissing w/o animation? The idea that a view controller could be deallocated in the middle of a handler makes no sense to me.  Especially since I'm not releasing anything during that handler - i'm hiding/showing buttons. Shouldn't I be able to rely on a single concurrency thread to run atomically?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Is your UIWebView being deallocated or is its delegate (I presume your view controller) being deallocated? The title of your post and the question seem to conflict on this point. Also - are you using ARC? Finally, assuming its the delegate being deallocated, what does the stack trace look like if you put a breakpoint in dealloc?

Comment: @bendytree I presume you are working on the main thread so your calls will be sequential in that if you dismiss the view controller first before clearing the delegate there is a good chance you will experience the issues you are having. If you clear the delegate first it will not matter whether your view being dismissed with or without animation as by the time the dismiss call is made, there is no delegate set so the webview will never call its delegate method.

Comment: Thanks CarlVeazey, I improved the title. It's both the web & the delegate that are deallocated. Not using ARC. Everything's on the main thread. I will extract the problem into a simple project this weekend & post it as 8vius advised.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make sure dealloc isn't called in the middle of my handler?

Don't release it in the middle of that callback. I would guess you're setting `self.myWebView = nil`, that releases the reference (unless it's declared `assign`), and if that is the end of its life cycle, i.e. would drop the `retainCount` to 0, it is deallocated immediately, in the middle of the callback. You can get around this by `retain`ing the web view at the beginning of the method (or at least before you nil it) and `autorelease`ing just before returning from the callback. The autorelease will wait until the callback finishes before processing the release. Or you can just not set that property to nil until some later time when you know it's safe.

Comment: What's weird is that I'm not releasing anything during the handler. I'm literally hiding & showing some buttons. The release happens from the dismiss finishing up, but it somehow interrupts my handler. Self retaining during the callback is a good option that I hadn't thought of, I'll give it a shot. It's still driving me nuts though that a handler on the main thread could be interrupted. From what I understand about the main thread, that shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your webview is nil before releasing it.

```
if(_webView !=nil){
  if (_webView.isLoading) {
    [_webView stopLoading];
  }
    [_webView removeFromSuperview];
    _webView.delegate = nil;
    [_webView release];
    _webView = nil;
}
```

Comment: In objective c, if `nil` is sent a message, nothing happens.  You can cal `[nil release]` as much as you want with no ill effects other than a bit of wasted processor time.

Comment: @Kevin what's the deal with [nil release]? I haven't done that.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter whether the webview is nil or not, that's not the issue here.

Comment: Actually it's the proper way to dealloc an object. Check first if it is nil to know if that object is allocated or not. And if it is not nil, deallocate it properly. The app will crash if you try to release an object that isn't even allocated.

Comment: "The app will crash if you try to release an object that isn't even allocated." This isn't c, you're not dereferencing `NULL`. I suggest you try it: add `[nil release]` to a project. Nothing happens. When you send a message to a `nil` pointer, the message simply isn't sent.

Comment: Actually it is a safe way to dealloc an object. Firstly all objects that was just declared first is pointed to nil. If you are a good programmer and you will use the object after you release it then you will point it to nil.

Comment: Sure, it's safe to check for `nil`, but it's  not necessary. And yes, setting a released variable to `nil` is good practice. But that's not what you seem to be saying.

Comment: I suggest you look at a few of Apple's sample programs.  I picked several at random and none of them checked for `nil` before `release`.